# Why does the decorator module force me to lift the inner function to the outer level?

Tags: python, python-2.7, decorator, memoization, python-decorators

As stated in the [memoization example](http://micheles.googlecode.com/hg/decorator/documentation.html#id6) in `decorator`'s docs, you can't use the nested function approach to implement memoization while preserving the function signature. Instead, you have to lift the inner function out, and then create a trivial decorator function:

```
def _memoize(func, *args, **kwargs):
    # the memoization code

def memoize(f):
    f.cache = {}
    return decorator(_memoize, f)
```

Why can't I use an inner function? Or are the docs misleading, meaning there is a way to use an inner function with `@decorator`? *Is there some sort of practical, implementation-based reason for why this is, or am I truly being forced to do it someone else's way?* I detest helper functions, and would like to avoid this approach if possible; if there is a hack to get it working (without, of course, writing it from scratch myself), I'd like to hear what it is.

It should be noted that without the need for initializing the `cache` or any other code which would not be a part of the inner function, of course, `@decorator` works just fine by not using an outer function at all (but then again, why use an inner function when you have no code outside the inner function?).

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "I detest helper functions". `_memoize` is a helper function, and in fact the exact _same_ helper function, whether it's at the top level or nested inside `memoize`.

Comment: @abarnert I realize that; I guess I meant to say that I detest helper functions which become accessible by name when you do `from module import *`. Which leads me to the question: if it's the exact same code, why am I being forced to do it one way without the option of the other? I tried to return `decorator(inner, func)` and the like from within the outer function acting as a decorator, with no luck, as well. There is no difference except that if you import my module you can get the broken `_memoize` function which throws an exception if you pass it a function without the `cache` attribute.

Comment: Well, there are standard ways to avoid that. Often, just discourage `from module import *`. When that isn't appropriate, provide an explicit `__all__`. (If you really want to, you can just `del` the function after you're done with it, or hide it away somewhere, etc.) But in this case… top-level module attributes that start with a single underscore are _already_ not imported by `from module import *`, so the problem doesn't even arise.

Comment: Things that start with underscores don't even get imported by `from x import *` anyway.

Comment: @abarnert I did *not* know that! Well, at least I have that much; I feel a lot safer using this approach after hearing that, at least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Requiring this is an intentional design choice of the `decorator` library, explained in the documentation (emphasis in the original):

> The difference with respect to the memoize_uw approach, which is based on nested functions, is that the decorator module forces you to lift the inner function at the outer level (*flat is better than nested*).

This is also explained right up in the motivation section of the Introduction:

> For instance, typical implementations of decorators involve nested functions, and we all know that flat is better than nested.

Of course "flat is better than nested" is part of [the Zen of Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/). But you may disagree that it applies here, or may think that some other principle overrides it.

If you violently disagree with the design principles behind the library, you're probably not going to be happy with it.

---

If you look into [the source code](http://micheles.googlecode.com/hg/decorator/src/decorator.py), you can see that the module makes some use of the assumption that you're going to be passing in top-level functions. For example, it copies `func_globals`, but does not try to copy non-local closure cells, and it expects `inspect` to have a module-level function to work with. In many cases, violating those assumptions won't actually hurt you. But if you insist on doing so, you will have to understand the code well enough to know when it *will* hurt you.

Comment: Yep, it's right in there. I understand that it's an intentional design decision (although I hope it can be hacked around), and I see the rationale behind it, but I often see that "flat is better than nested" matters more when you are trying to balance readable indent levels and an 80 character per line limit, which is why you see people discouraging lots of nested control structures. But, if it were so important, why have closures?

Comment: @2rs2ts: The Zen isn't a set of absolute rules, but a set of principles that have to be balanced. There are clearly cases when a closure, or making a separate function object for each call, or whatever is the obvious way to do what you want to do—and in those cases, the obvious way to do it is to nest a function. So, do it. But when you get no benefit from nesting, don't do it.

Comment: @2rs2ts: To take one of those examples further: When the obvious design uses a closure, you can always do without one in various ways—with a class, mutable defaults, or even a global mapping with appropriate keys (together with a bunch of extra code). And that would avoid nesting. But doing so would also violate "Simple is better than complex" and "Beautiful is better than ugly" and TOOWDTI and "If the implementation is hard to explain". So, you balance the principles and decide to go with nesting instead of some complex and hacky mess to avoid it.

Comment: Of course. However (this is entirely my opinion), I see a benefit in both readability and maintainability with using a nested function in this case - because the two functions are almost certainly 1-1 coupled, they are grouped together. To me, this *seems to be* the obvious way to do it. Personally, I like Python because it has 10,000 ways to skin cats, and if I don't like one way I can use another, so it's fine if my opinion is divergent. I just don't like being told what to do.

Comment: In response to your edit about the source code: thank you, that explains a lot. I was having trouble understanding it, so I just gave up and came for help. That explanation makes this clear enough for me to accept it.

Comment: @2rs2ts: Remember that "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it." (But also keep in mind the next rule, and the sly joke Tim Peters inserted about em dashes in ASCII _not_ having one obvious way to do it…)